# Are there any lightweight markups that are easily customized?

Tags: python, markdown, restructuredtext

I've written some amounts of LaTeX but nowadays I'm feeling lazy and I would like to write my next bigger project in Markdown, reStructuredText or Textile for easy readability. Unfortunately, I'd like to have some of that TeX customizability and write some own syntax constructs to meet my semantic needs.

One thing I want for such a markup language is that there are existing plugins/filters to generate LaTeX and (X)HTML output.

Because my needs might not be fulfilled out of the box, my side question is that since many of the newer parsers are written in Python, is there any particularly clean Python implementation in which I would easily insert new syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at

http://sphinx.pocoo.org/

using

Restructured Text

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html

Comment: Yes, at first I thought Sphinx was too Python-centric but it seems I can write anything I want. The inline syntax for custom roles is a bit ugly with rST, but I can live with that.